# Flutter Hive - how to list objects from box as a select field elements

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-hive

I'm making a mobile Flutter app with simple Hive database. I have some Account objects in my Hive box and I need to show it to the user as a selectable list (for example in a DropdownButton). How can I implement that?

I've tried to give the values as a list but I'm getting an error `The argument type 'List<Account>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Account>>'.`

```
DropdownButton(
    items: Hive.box<Account>('accounts').values.toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late, but you are trying to give the DropdownButton a list of of Accounts. But DropdownButton only accepts a list of DropDownMenuItems.

Try to map your List to a List<DropdownMenuItem<Account>>.